# How can I put elements of an array inside object which is inside an array in separate divs?

Tags: javascript

I want to put the elements of an array in separate divs dynamically. The array is inside an object which is inside an array. I want to display each value of options property in separate divs. How can I achieve that through javascript? Thanks for your great help.

```
 var antonyms = [

 {
   question: "soft",
   options: ["dark", "white", "heavy", "hard", "down", "pretty", 
   "butter", "cotton"],
   answer: "hard"

  } ]


var x = "";

var i = 0;

function elements() {

if (i < antonyms.length) {

x += '<div class=option>' + antonyms[i].options.join(" ") + '</div>';

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = x;

 i++;

    }

    x = "";

   }

elements();
```

Comment: Use `while` instead of `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope next code helps you, Basically I'm assuming you have an **outer array** with question `objects` and for each one, you need to generate an `HTML` structure. So, I will define a method that takes one question object and generate the related `HTML` structure, then you can call that method for each question or for specifics ones.

```js
var antonyms = [
  {
    question: "soft",
    options: ["dark", "white", "heavy", "hard", "down", "pretty", "butter", "cotton"],
    answer: "hard"
  },
  {
    question: "test",
    options: ["one", "two"],
    answer: "two"
  }
];

// Define a method that generate the HTML for one question.
function getQuestionHtml(q)
{
    let qHtml = "<h2>" + q.question + " options:</h2>";
    qHtml += q.options.map(o => '<div class="option">' + o + '</div>').join("");
    return qHtml;
}

// Start showing the first question. Click event will show next question.

let container = document.getElementById("container");
let button = document.getElementById("btnNext");
let qIdx = 0;
container.innerHTML = getQuestionHtml(antonyms[qIdx]);

button.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    qIdx += 1;

    if (qIdx < antonyms.length)
        container.innerHTML = getQuestionHtml(antonyms[qIdx]);
    else
        button.disabled = true;
});
```

```css
.option {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
<br>
<button id="btnNext" type="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: A little more help please. I need these values not all at a time, but on click event, first soft options then test options and so on.

Comment: @TarunRathore Ok, I have updated the answer, you can take that as a base approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `join()` to mash all of the array elements together in a string, you can use a loop to create a `<div>` element for each array element. I suggest that you look at the `map()` function for an array.